# How to change the account that is interacting with the deployed smart contract on Ganache?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, ganache

When I enter truffle console and start interacting with the deployed contract truffle uses the first address, how to change the address for testing ?

```
user@user:~/workspace/smart-contract$ truffle console 

truffle(ganache)> setAddress("0x0000000....); // how to set the addres ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the truffle.js file for truffle to use some address other than the default address which just happens to be the first address in your Ganache blockchain. You can do that by assigning any available ganache address to the `from` property in the file.

Comment: do you actually mean truffle-config.js ? here is the configuration and it doesn't work: advanced: {port: 7545,      network_id: 5777,gas: 8500000,sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
      gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
      from: "0xf1174C51Bf83fD36fB2E6Eec4A469Db879A6aa94",        // Account to send txs from (default: accounts[0])
      websockets: true        // Enable EventEmitter interface for web3 (default: false)
    }